# Best way to run .JSX scripts from a customized interface?

Tags: html, scripting, com, jsx

I am quite new to scripting, so bear with me here. I've done my best to research this question here already, but am a bit unsure of how to phrase this question and get results that I'm looking for.

I've made quite a few .JSX scripts for Photoshop (CS6), and am basically looking for a way to organize them into a custom "panel" as buttons to run them. My goal is to have maximum customization of the appearance of the panel, as far as icon size and appearance goes: I want to be able to have different-sized buttons in an irregular layout, and have different "labels" (images) represent different buttons.

I've explored options such as PowerPro, but it focuses on utility, and right now I'm most interested in visual customization.

Would it be possible to run these scripts from something like an HTML document? Not looking to run anything remotely, server/client configuration or anything like that. My preferred platform is Windows. I appreciate any insight.